# Large integer help

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The integer

$5685858885855807765856785858569666876865656567858576786786785^{22}$

has 6436343 divisors. Using only a scientific calculator, find a way to show it has exactly 5 prime divisors.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Calling $5685858885855807765856785858569666876865656567858576786786785$ as $n$, we have that $n^{22}$ has $6436343$ divisors. Let $n = p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2} \ldots p_k^{a_k}$, where $p_j$ are primes and $a_j \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Then $$n^{22} = p_1^{22a_1}p_2^{22a_2} \ldots p_k^{22a_k}$$
Hence, the number of divisors is
$$(1+22a_1)(1+22a_2)\cdots(1+22a_k) = 6436343 = 23^5$$
<s>Hence, we get that $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{k=5}$ and $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = a_5 = 1}$. Hence, we get that
$$\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{5685858885855807765856785858569666876865656567858576786786785 = p_1 p_2 p_3 p_4 p_5}$$</s>
By adding the digits, we find that $3$ doesn't divide $n$. Hence, $p_1 = 5$.

The actual prime factorization (obtained using Wolframalpha) is
$$5 \times 13 \times 647 \times 25414873859387 \times 5319740909859534399143659720463597175586901$$

**EDIT**

A good point was raised by Mike in his comments. If we have $$(1+22a_1)(1+22a_2)\cdots(1+22a_k) = 23^5$$ This only implies $k \leq 5$. We also know that $k \geq 2$, since $5 \vert n$. So the answer is incomplete.

**EDIT**

Some more updates after some very insightful comments from Mike, Henry and Pambos. Let us assume that we can use divisibility rules to check divisibility up-to $13$ and divide $n$ by numbers up-to $13$. Note that $5 \vert n$ and $13 \vert n$. Hence, $n = 65 \times m$. Let $m = \prod_{j=1}^k p_j^{a_j}$. Hence, we get that $23 \times 23 \times \prod_{j=1}^k (1+22a_j) = 23^5 \implies \prod_{j=1}^k (1+22a_j) = 23^3$. Hence, the number of distinct primes in $m$ can be at most $3$. We want to show that the number of distinct primes dividing $m$ is exactly $3$.

Case $1$: $m$ is a perfect prime power i.e. $m = p^a$ where $p\geq 17$. This means we have $(1+22a) = 23^3 \implies a = \dfrac{23^3-1}{22} = 553$. But the number $m$ is only $59$ digits long. But then $p^{553} \geq 17^{553}$ is more than $500$ digits long. Hence, not possible. This means that the number of distinct primes dividing $m$ is either $2$ or $3$.

Case $2$: $m$ is of the form $m=p_1^{a_1} p_2^{a_2}$. In this case, we have $$(1+22a_1)(1+22a_2) = 23^3$$ Without loss of generality, let us take $a_1 = 1$ and $a_2 = 24$ i.e. $m = p_1 p_2^{24}$.

$$p_2^{8} \equiv 1 \pmod{2^5}$$
$$p_2^{6} \equiv 1 \pmod{3^2}$$
$$p_2^{4} \equiv 1 \pmod{5^1}$$
$$p_2^{6} \equiv 1 \pmod{7^1}$$
$$p_2^{12} \equiv 1 \pmod{13^1}$$
Hence, we get that $$p_2^{24} \equiv 1 \pmod{131040}$$
But we have $m \equiv 74369 \pmod{131040}$. (Note that I have assumed that we have divisibility rules up-to $13$. Divisibility by $2^5$ is trivial since all we need to check is if the last $5$ digits of $m$ is divisible by $2^5$.)

This means $p_1 \equiv 74369 \pmod{131040}$. This gives us $p_2 < p_1$ and hence $p_2^{24} < 10^{54} \implies p_2 < 10^{0.25} 10^{2} < 178$.

Comment: That's extraordinary. I was just typing up a far inferior response. +1

Comment: Very nice one lol

Comment: @Ethan I'm not sure "lol" makes much sense in this context.

Comment: Ethan uses lol like Jasper uses QED. I think it's a personal catchphrase or something.

Comment: Marvis how did you know it was the 23^5, did you type that in on wolfram alpha and did it list it as an alternative representation? Amazing fast answer though

Comment: @Ethan Yes, I used WA to get the prime factorization of $6436343 $ and was pleasantly surprised to find that it was $23^5$. However, I think you could easily obtain the factorization using some simple divisibility rules or using your calculator as well.

Comment: Dumb question.  Without factoring $n$, does this show that it can't have less than 5 factors?  For example, does anything prevent $k=4,a_1=a_2=a_3=1,a_4=24?$

Comment: @Mike Do you mean $n$ or the number of divisors?

Comment: Amazing answer though

Comment: @marvis I meant using $6436343=23^5$, without explicitly factoring $n$ out as you had done at the end.

Comment: @Mike Valid point. Yes. $\prod_{m=1}^k (1+a_m) = 23^5 \implies k \leq 5$. Hence, we only get $k \in \{2,3,4,5\}$. Currently, I do not have an immediate way to conclude that $k$ has to be indeed $5$. Do you have an easy way out?

Comment: @Marvis I wish I did.  The number is certainly long enough to have a single prime factor repeated several times.

Comment: @Mike: Can you explain "The number is certainly long enough to have a single prime factor repeated several times" please?

Comment: @pambos I count $61$ digits in $n$.  $5\times7^{24}\times11^{24}$ has only $46$.  That number to the 22nd power would also have $23^5$ factors.  If you consider just one prime factor to the 24th power, a 61 digit number is still more than big enough to be divisible by some quite sizable prime numbers.

Comment: @Mike: The numbers $5\cdot17^{24}\cdot19^{24}$ and $5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot251^{24}$ have $61$ digits.

Comment: @Mavis: You can reject $k=2$ since $2^{(23^3-1)/22}=2^{553} \gt 10^{166}$ and  $2^{(23^4-1)/22}$ is even bigger.

Comment: @Marvis: Also you can eliminate the case $k=3$ if you look $\pmod {10}$. Easily $5 \mid n$ and $25 \nmid n$. So in case $k=3$ necessarily $n=5\cdot p^{24}\cdot q^{24}$ for some primes $p,q$. The last digit of $\frac{n}{5}$ is $7$ but $1^{24}, \ 3^{24}, \ 7^{24}, \ 9^{24} \equiv 1 \pmod {10}$.

Comment: @pambos Very nice.  That still leaves one case left to disprove though.

Comment: @Pambos - Just beat me to it!  It's just Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: @Pambos Nice. Note that $k=3$ can also have a decomposition of the form $5pq^{553}$. But yes, $q^{553} > 10^{61}$ even for $q=2$. Hence, it can be ruled out. Nice Pambos.

Comment: @Henry Yes. Neat. A very nice collaborative proof in progress :).

Comment: Theres a $\frac{6}{\pi^2}=.607927..$ chance that the number of prime divisors of k is equal to $\frac{ln(d(k))}{ln(2)}$

Comment: @Ethan $\omega(n)$ has mean and variance $\ln(\ln(n)) \approx 8.03192$. Hence, the probability that $k \leq 4$ is approximately $0.0775$.

Comment: What do you mean? if d(k) is square free its equal to $2^{\omega(k)}$, therefore $\frac{ln(d(k)}{ln(2)}=\omega(k)$ when k is square free, and the asymptotic probability of any integer being square free is $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$

Comment: @Ethan We do not know that $n$ is square free yet. If $n$ is square free, then we can immediately conclude that $n=p_1p_2p_3p_4p_5$. What I meant is the asymptotic for $\omega(n)$ goes as $\ln \ln n$ and with variance $\ln \ln n$. See equation $3$ and $5$. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DistinctPrimeFactors.html

Comment: @Ethan A better asymptotic as the above link shows is $\omega(n) \sim \ln \ln n + 0.2615$ with variance $\ln \ln n - 1.8357$. For our case, this gives us $\omega(n) \approx 8.2934$, and variance is $6.19622$. Hence, $\mathbb{P}(\omega(n) \leq 4) = \mathbb{P}(z \leq \dfrac{-4.2934}{2.489}) = 0.0423$. But $\mathbb{P}(\omega(n) \leq 5) = \mathbb{P}(z \leq \dfrac{-3.2934}{2.489}) = 0.0923$ and $\mathbb{P}(\omega(n) \leq 3) = \mathbb{P}(z \leq \dfrac{-5.2934}{2.489}) = 0.017$. Hence, given that the number of prime factors is either $4$ or $5$, the probability it is $4$ is approximately $0.327$.

Answer (score 5):

Im not really answering my own question, but its to large to put in a comment, I was thinking of using the fact that $$\lim_{s\to\infty}\frac{\ln(d(k^s))}{\ln(1+s)}=\text{number of prime divisors $k$ has}$$ $d(k)=$ number of divisors of $k$

And then using the fact $s$ is very large, I could say $$\frac{\ln(d(k^{22}))}{\ln(23)}\sim \text{number of prime divisors $k$ has}$$
It gives me $5$ also, but this isn't really a proof, it works with $s=2$, also btw.

Also I was just experimenting it looks like $\dfrac{\ln(d(k))}{\ln(2)}=$ (number of prime diviors of $k$) very often.